# For loop by intervals

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop

This should be a very easy issue, but  I am stuck.

I have an array representing a certain measure for each angle of a circle, so it has 360 elements. I have to check the minimum value of those measures in a neighbourhood of an angle +/- 10 degrees. This is a function,so the angle can change. The function is like this:

```
double MyClass::FindMin(int angle) {
  lower_limit = x-10;
  upper_limit = x+10;
  for(int i=lower_limit; i<upper_limit; i++) {
    //Find the minimum
  }
  return minimum;
}
```

If I the value of the angle is 300, the for cycle like will be this:

```
for(int i=290; i<310; i++)
```

The problem comes when the angle will be around 360:

```
for(int i=355; i<365; i++)
```

This clearly will not work because the array has 360 values.

Is there an elegant way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the modulus operator to compute a new index `j` that wraps correctly:

```
double findmin(int angle) {
  int lower_limit = angle + 350;
  int upper_limit = angle + 370;
  double minimum = 0.0;

  for(int i = lower_limit; i < upper_limit; i++) {
    // compute a new index j that wraps using the modulus operator
    int j = i % 360;

    // find minimum using j 
  }

  return minimum;
}
```

**Edit**: Modified based on feedback from @EdHeal in the comments.

Comment: Might want to consider adding 360 to both limits to prevent negative indexes

Comment: Still not quite right - Should be `int lower_limit = (angle + 350)` and `int upper_limit = angle + 370`

Comment: Not sure I follow, I thought you wanted the previous 10 angles. So if you pass in 0 wouldn't that be 350 - 360 ?

Comment: Would be 350 -> 370 -> With the % operator 350-> 360, 0 -> 10

Comment: Ah I see, I forgot about negatives. Makes sense now.

Comment: You do not need the % operator for the limits. It messes up the loop - since the upper limit could end up smaller that the lower limit

Comment: I Should be missing something: if I modify the upper and lower limits as above they will become (in case of a 0 degree angle)  0 and 10 and so I will not check the value in the interval 350-360?

Comment: @GiorgioR Yep, I had a mistake that EdHeal corrected

Comment: Inside the cycle shouldn't be something like `if(i>360) { j=i%360; } else { j=i; }`?

Comment: If `i < 360` then `i % 360` results in `i`.

Comment: @GiorgioR: That's not necessary and just makes the code harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

Well if I were you I would write sth like this(after taking comments into consideration :)

```
int numOfIterations = 0;
int minAngle = currentAngle + 350;
while(numOfIterations < 20) // as you want it from -10 to 10 from your angle
{ 
    minAngle = minAngle % 360; 
    doSomething(i);
    i++;
    numOfIterations++;
}
```

Comment: I recommend you expand sth out to the whole word to prevent confusion.

Comment: Based on OP, starting angle can be as low as -10. Code will not work for negative i.

Answer (score 0):

You must have problems not only with angles around 360, but also with angles around 0. Also note that you've missed the "+10" angle. My suggestion is (developing Ajris's answer):

```
double MyClass::FindMin( int angle ) {
  int current_angle = ( x + 350 ) % 360;
  for( int i = 0; i < 21; ++i, ++current_angle ) {
    current_angle = current_angle % 360;
    //Find the minimum
  }
  return minimum;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Despite the upvotes or downvotes none of the (pre-edited) answers using % take into account the fact that i can be negative.

Inside your loop use:

```
j=i<360?i:i-360;
j=i<0?i+360:i;
```

and use `j` for whatever you are using `i` for.